# Apache mod_deflate not deflating…

Tags: apache-2.2, deflate

I'm having some trouble with `mod_deflate`… Specifically, that it's not actually deflating anything.

I'm running Apache2 and Debian 4. I've `a2enmod deflate`'d, and put this in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf`:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain
```

Yet, when I `curl -I http://host/robots.txt`, I don't see any headers suggesting the output is being deflated (and this suspicion is confirmed when I `tail` `access.log`, and see that my `DeflateFilterNote` in the logs is `-`). I know that "it's plugged in", because if I add:

```
SetEnv force-gzip "yes"
```

The output is compressed.

So, am I doing something obvious and stupid wrong? Or… What?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mod_deflate` won't send compressed output unless the client indicates that it supports it. The client does this by sending a header of `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the original request.

`curl` doesn't do this by default. But you can instruct it to do so with the command:

```
curl --compressed -I http://host/robots.txt
```

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. I was mistaking curl's `Accept: */*` for `Accept-encoding`. Clearly tinkering with HTTP is the wrong thing to do first-thing monday morning…